# Java: A defined paint method for my frame won't call repaint() when referenced from another class

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, class, repaint

I am trying to call this constructor from another class, but when I create the new thread, it doesn't ever call repaint. If I just call the run() method from the main method in the class, it works exactly as expected. It seems like my repaint() method isn't getting called from the other class. I was worried that my other class was still doing calculations, but even after putting it in a thread, I had no luck.

Code:

```
public class MakeTransparent implements Runnable{
private int i;
private static int dollars;
private float transparency;

public MakeTransparent(int dollars){

    this.setDollars(dollars);
    this.transparency = 1;
    this.i = 300;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tiddlybiscuits"){
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public void paint(Graphics arg0) {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)arg0;
            super.paint(g2);
            g2.setColor(getBackground());
            g2.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(),this.getHeight());
            g2.setColor(Color.CYAN);
            g2.setFont(g2.getFont().deriveFont(50, 200F));
            //System.out.println(arg0.getFontMetrics());
            String string = "+$";
            Composite c = AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, getTransparency());
            g2.setComposite(c);
            g2.drawString(string + getDollars(), 30, getI());
            try {Thread.sleep(40);} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            setI(getI()-5);
            setTransparency(getTransparency()-.03f);
            repaint();
        }
    };
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.setBackground(new Color(1,55,134,0));

    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    try { Thread.sleep(1400); } catch (InterruptedException e) {    }
    frame.dispose();
}
```

Comment: This `try {Thread.sleep(40);} catch (InterruptedException e) {}` and `setTransparency(getTransparency()-.03f);` and `repaint();` should never be called from within any `paint` method.  Don't override `paint` of `JFrame` or any other top level container, instead, create a custom class extending from something like `JPanel` and overide it's `paintComponent` method instead

Comment: Why are you calling repaint() in the paint() method?

Comment: Swing is also a single threaded environment and is not thread safe, you should only ever create and modify your UI from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread

Comment: From your description, you seem to be blocking the Event Dispatching Thread. Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details.  You can't simply create another thread and assume that your UI code will run within it exclusively, that's not how this works.  Most UI frameworks have a single thread (main thread or event thread) which is responsible for processing events and managing updates.

Comment: Take a closer look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting works in Swing

Comment: @kirbyquerby I'm calling repaint() there because it forces the paint method to do what I want rather than doing whatever it wants, which is extremely ambiguous to me

Comment: Because your code is broken. Don't ever call `repaint()` from within any painting method. And as @MadProgrammer states, never ever delay a painting method, not unless you want your code to become unresponsive.

Comment: @Nexion21 Swing uses a passive rendering algorithm, this means painting is done ad-hoc and the discretion of the repaint manager. You make requests for updates, but it's up to the repaint manager to decide when painting should take place, you don't control painting in Swing, the sooner you accept that, the easier your life will become.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Don't call `Thread.sleep` EVER from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread
- Don't call any method that might cause a `repaint` to occur from within in paint method, this will cause an infinite update loop which will eventually consume your CPU
- Avoid overriding `paint` of top level containers like `JFrame`, apart from not been double buffered, most windows contain other components (`JRootPane`, `contentPane`, `glassPane`) all which can interfere with what you are trying to paint
- Swing is a single threaded frame work and is not thread safe.  This means that you should never perform any long running or blocking operations from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread and you should never create or modify any UI component from outside the Event Dispatching Thread.
- There is only ever one EDT and ALL UI code will run within in.  Things like painting are ALWAYS executed within the EDT automatically.

Take a look at:

- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)
- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)
- [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)
- [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

for more details and ideas about how to work within the frameworks requirements

[image: Fade]

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Composite;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                TestPane tp = new TestPane();
                Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        float t = tp.getTransparancy() - 0.03f;
                        if (t < 0) {
                            t = 0;
                            ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
                        }
                        int i = tp.getI();

                        tp.setI(i - 1);
                        System.out.println(t);
                        tp.setTransparancy(t);
                    }
                });

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(tp);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                timer.start();
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private float transparancy = 1f;
        private int i = 200;
        private int dollars;

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 200);
        }

        public void setTransparancy(float value) {
            if (transparancy != value) {
                float old = transparancy;
                this.transparancy = value;
                firePropertyChange("transparancy", old, transparancy);
                repaint();
            }
        }

        public float getTransparancy() {
            return transparancy;
        }

        public int getDollars() {
            return dollars;
        }

        public int getI() {
            return i;
        }

        public void setI(int value) {
            if (i != value) {
                float old = i;
                this.i = value;
                firePropertyChange("i", old, i);
                repaint();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(getBackground());
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
            g2d.setColor(Color.CYAN);
            g2d.setFont(g2d.getFont().deriveFont(50, 200F));
            //System.out.println(arg0.getFontMetrics());
            String string = "+$";
            Composite c = AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, getTransparancy());
            g2d.setComposite(c);
            g2d.drawString(string + getDollars(), 30, getI());
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Well I may not understand everything in here, (firepropertychange seems like it replaces an old variable with a new one but I'm not sure of the advantage). Would you recommend using this as a sort of template for future projects?

There's no way I'd ever have thought of using a timer to change variables, which is why I was doing it directly in the paint method. I've only ever done things with user interaction, so I wasn't sure how to update any variables without that.

Thank you for your help, this was absolutely wonderful. You both solved my problem and taught me a lot with this answer

Comment: firePropertyChanged is an event notification mechnism, which allows interested parties to see when a named property is changed. It's nice to have because you don't need to design in additional code to see when a state is changed (calling some other method, overriding methods, etc) and allows other interested parties to take action. It also means you don't need to create your own notification system. I'd use it where you think I might be important to you and in the future for your given code.

Comment: Swing is actually really flexible and dynamic, but you need to understand how it operates in order to leverage its power. The Swing Timer and SwingWorker are just two more tools if your toolbox that you'll need to learn to use ;)